# How to join bag in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

First I have two data files.

largefile.txt:

```
1001    {(1,-1),(2,-1),(3,-1),(4,-1)}
```

smallfile.txt:

```
1002    {(1,0.04),(2,0.02),(4,0.03)}
```

and I want smallfile.txt like this:

```
1002    {(1,0.04),(2,0.02),(3,-1),(4,0.03)}
```

What type of join that I can do something like this?

```
A = LOAD './largefile.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:int, a:bag{tuple(time:int,value:float)});

B = LOAD './smallfile.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:int, b:bag{tuple(time:int,value:float)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clear your requirement a bit ? Do you want to join on first column/field from largefile.txt and smallfile.txt with same value (for eg 1002). If that is the case you can simple do this :-

A = LOAD './largefile.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:int, a:bag{tuple(time:int,value:float)});

A = Foreach A generate id , FLATTEN(a) as time,value ;

B = LOAD './smallfile.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:int, b:bag{tuple(time:int,value:float)});

B = Foreach B generate id , FLATTEN(b) as time,value ;

joined = join A by A.id , B by B.id;